# mysql splitting a very big row to 4 columns at a time

Tags: insert, rows

Hi all im trying to scrape data from this website and enter it to my database

$html = file_get_html('http://www.matchmoney.com.gr/odds-comparison/');

using this code (php simple dom)

```
$table = $html->find('table', 2);


//OMADES


foreach($table->find('tr') as $fuck){


$one0= $fuck->find('td', 1)->plaintext;  
$one1= $fuck->find('td', 2)->plaintext;  
$one2= $fuck->find('td', 3)->plaintext;
$one3= $fuck->find('td', 4)->plaintext;   




echo $one0." | ".$one1." | ".$one2." vs ".$one3."<br>";

ins1($DBHOST,$DBUSER,$DBPASS,$DBNAME,$TABLE_NAME,$one0,$one1,$one2,$one3);

    }
```

what i want is like i echo it on php every 4 records and change row to insert it the same way to mysql, what happens now is all records are outputted on mysql in row1 while i want to insert it like row1,row2,row3,row4 then row1,row2 again etc

output on php is like this

13:05 | 799 | ΣΑΠΟΡΟ vs ΡΟΑΣΟ ΚΟΥΜΑΜΟΤΟ

14:30 | 800 | ΓΚΙΛΑΝΓΚ vs ΜΠΑΛΕΣΤΙΕ ΣΕΝΤΡΑΛ

18:00 | 801 | ΛΙΕΤΑΒΑ ΖΟΝΑΒΑ vs ΟΥΤΕΝΙΣ ΟΥΤΕΝΑ

18:30 | 802 | ΛΑΧΤΙ ΑΚΑΤΕΜΙΑ vs ΒΑΖΑΚΟΣΚΙ

18:30 | 803 | ΜΠΣ vs ΣΟΥΝΤΕΤ

18:30 | 2862 | ΧΟΛΒΙΚΕΝ vs ΕΡΓΚΡΙΤΕ

19:00 | 2855 | ΙΝΟΦΕΤ ΙΙ vs ΤΟΥΛΕΒΙΚ

on mysql i get

13:05 | 799 | ΣΑΠΟΡΟ vs ΡΟΑΣΟ ΚΟΥΜΑΜΟΤΟ | 14:30 | 800 | ΓΚΙΛΑΝΓΚ vs ΜΠΑΛΕΣΤΙΕ ΣΕΝΤΡΑΛ | 18:00 | 801 | ΛΙΕΤΑΒΑ ΖΟΝΑΒΑ vs ΟΥΤΕΝΙΣ ΟΥΤΕΝΑ | 18:30 | 802 | ΛΑΧΤΙ ΑΚΑΤΕΜΙΑ vs ΒΑΖΑΚΟΣΚΙ |18:30 | 803 | ΜΠΣ vs ΣΟΥΝΤΕΤ | 18:30 | 2862 | ΧΟΛΒΙΚΕΝ vs ΕΡΓΚΡΙΤΕ | 19:00 | 2855 | ΙΝΟΦΕΤ ΙΙ vs ΤΟΥΛΕΒΙΚ

all in row1 (without the |'s)

my insert function

```
function ins1($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname,$table_name,$one1,$one2,$one3,$one4){

    $conn=mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());


    $sql=sprintf("INSERT INTO %s(id, time, team1, team2) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($table_name),
        mysql_real_escape_string($id),
        mysql_real_escape_string($time),
        mysql_real_escape_string($team1),
        mysql_real_escape_string($team2));

    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_close($conn);


}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

got it solved it was my stupid mistake ignore the above cheers